# Lumen how to pass variable to notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, lumen

I'm using the following plugin in my lumen:

```
"illuminate/notifications": "^8.11",    
"laravel-notification-channels/telegram": "^0.5.0",
```

After tried many example available online, finally I can send out with the following code set:

```
    // App/Console/Command/abc.php
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    
    use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramChannel;
    use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
    use App\Helpers\TGNotification;
    
     Notification::route(TelegramChannel::class, '-123456')
                                ->notify(new TGNotification($tg));
```

Above is the code in console command and the below is a helper file:

```
// App/Helpers/TGNotification.php
namespace App\Helpers;

use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class TGNotification extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TelegramChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTelegram($notifiable)
    {
        $url = "http://www.google.com";
        return TelegramMessage::create()
            // Optional recipient user id.
            // ->to($notifiable->telegram_user_id)
            ->to("-123456")
            // Markdown supported.
            ->content($notifiable->msg)
            
            // (Optional) Blade template for the content.
            // ->view('notification', ['url' => $url])
            
            // (Optional) Inline Buttons
            ->button('Hello', $url)
            ->button('World', $url);
    }
}
```

However, I'm not able to pass the variable from abc.php to TGNotification.php.
It just don't work if i'm using any example of this plugin available online. Could anyone please advise? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send your parameter in the `construct` method:

```php
class TGNotification extends Notification
{
    protected $tg;

    public function __construct($tg)
    {
        $this->tg = $tg;
    }
}
```

or, you can use the setter and getter methods.

Comment: the `$tg` should be protected function I believe